# Comparing absolute value of variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

We have
$$0 < |x-a| < \delta $$

How do we get
$$a - \delta < x < a + \delta $$
?

When I add $a$ to both sides I get:
$$a<|x|<a+\delta$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition,
$|x|=x$ if $x\ge0$ and $|x|=-x$ if $x<0$. Thus, $|x|\ge0$ for all $x$.

Here,
$$|x-a|<\delta$$

---

Case 1: $x-a>0$

$$|x-a|=x-a<\delta$$
$$x<a+\delta$$

As $\delta>0$, we have $-\delta<0$, i.e., $x-a>-\delta$ which gives $x>a-\delta$.

---

Case 2: $x-a<0$
$$|x-a|=-(x-a)<\delta$$
$$x-a>-\delta$$
$$x>a-\delta$$

As $\delta>0$, we have $x-a<\delta$ which gives $x<a+\delta$.

Thus,
$$a-\delta<x<a+\delta$$

Comment: Sorry I'm having a hard time understanding ...

Comment: @EricJohnson The definition of $|x|$ is given as in the first line. Notice that how $|x|$ can be simplified depends on whether it is $\ge0$ or $<0$. In this case, replace $|x|$ by $|x-a|$. So, the simplification depends on whether $x-a\ge0$ or $x-a<0$. Thus, these two cases have been handled separately.

Comment: "As $δ>0δ>0$, we have $−δ<0−δ<0, i.e., x−a>−δx−a>−δ$ which gives $x>a−δx>a−δ.$" This is the line where I lose track

Comment: @EricJohnson When you multiply an inequality by $-1$, the signs get interchanged. Thus, doing so for $\delta>0$, we get $-\delta<0$. But in our case, we assumed that $x-a>0$. If $-\delta<0$, then it follows that $x-a>-\delta$. Now, adding $a$ to both sides, we get $x>a-\delta$.

Comment: Ohhhhh :) got it

Comment: In theory, doesn't the last line in Case 1 prove it by itself?

Comment: @EricJohnson It is quite obvious. I wrote to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

$|y| < \delta$ **iff** $-\delta < y < \delta$.

Then you have $-\delta < x-a < \delta$.

Add $a$ throughout to get $a-\delta < x < a+\delta$.

Note that the last equation is **not** equivalent to the first condition given, for equivalence
you need to add the condition $x \neq a$.

Elaboration of first line:

Suppose $|y| < \delta$. Then either $y \ge 0$, in which case $0 \le y < \delta$ (and so $-\delta < y < \delta$) or
$y < 0$ in which case $|y| = -y $ and we have $0 \le -y < \delta$. Multiplying
the latter by $-1$ (and reversing the inequalities) gives
$-\delta < y \le 0$ (and so $-\delta < y < \delta$).

Now suppose $-\delta < y < \delta$. If $y \ge 0$, we have $|y|=y < \delta$.
If $y < 0$ we have $|y|=-y$ and since $y > -\delta$ we have (multiplying across by $-1$) $-y < -\delta$ and so $|y|=-y < \delta$.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand the first line

Comment: @EricJohnson: I added an elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't actually give that result. For instance, $x = a$ satisfies the second conclusion, but not the first.

Comment: x cannot be equal to a because $0 < |x-a|$

Comment: Yes, but $x= a$ *is* a solution to the second equation. Therefore the two equations are not equivalent. It's true that the first implies the second (any $x$ satisfying the first also satisfies the second), however.

Answer (score 0):

One has $0\lt |b|\lt c\iff -c\lt b\lt c$. We apply that to $|x-a|\lt\delta$ to get

$$-\delta\lt x-a\lt \delta$$

And this implies

$$a-\delta\lt x\lt a+\delta$$

Comment: Is $0<|b|<c⟺−c<b<c$ a rule? If so what is it called ?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, but may not help you in the future.

I think you should begin with an example and some words, rather than trying to "add $a$ to both sides".

Think about the situation when (for example) $a = 3$ and $\delta = 1$. Then the condition says you care about the values of $x$ for which the distance from $3$ is less than $1$ but bigger than $0$. You should draw the picture that shows why  $x$ is between $3-1=2$ and $3+1=4$ (values $1$ away from $3$), but not $3$ itself.